# How to set static column in webdatarocks?

Tags: javascript, webdatarocks

Can I create a static column in `webdatarocks`?

for example, I have data like this. (please see in the picture)

there is no data for "3. Mod" *Jobcategory* in 2. Dies Face, but I want to set all **jobcategory** for every **linecategory**, although no data.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

`webdatarocks` hides the columns that have no data to save space.

So, as I see right now, to show `2. Dies Face` -> `3. Mod` column the only way is to append your data set with empty or zero data for this intersection.